# Form didn't reach controller

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this simple login form (Razor Page)

File: Index.chstml

```
    <form method="post">
    <label asp-for="Username"></label><br />
    <input asp-for="Username" /><br />

    <label asp-for="Password"></label><br />
    <input asp-for="Password" /><br />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

File: Index.cshtml.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public Login Login { get; set; }

    public ActionResult OnPost()
    {         
        if(Login.Username.Equals("user") && Login.Password.Equals("123"))
        {
            RedirectToPage("./Secure/Home.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
            return Page();
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in OnPost, it doesn't reach there.

Comment: Works for me once I included `Login.` in each of the `asp-for` attributes, but since the code you posted doesn't compile, I'm guessing that there is an issue somewhere in your actual code that you didn't include in your post.

Comment: It's okay. After I re-generate the page using scaffolding option, it works now. Not sure why manually create it does not work though.